# Include external julius file

Tags: javascript, haskell, yesod

Let's say I have

Page1.hamlet
Page1.julius
Page1.lucius

- Page2.hamlet
- Page2.julius
- Page2.lucius

Initially I had those JS files that I would like to convert to .julius

- Alert.js
- Page1.js
- Page2.js

Normaly i would C/P Page1.js and Page2.js directly in the right .julius file. Which is fine by me. But i also need to somehow include another julius that would contain Alert.js so that i do not have to duplicate the code from Alert.js in Page1.julius and Page2.julius

I can't seem to find anything anywhere about that kind of usage.
We could say that I am looking for this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/page.js"></script>
```

In yesod/haskell format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add common javascript to a page using the addScriptRemote function in the handler....
For instance, this would add jquery to your webpage.

```
addScriptRemote "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"
```

(of course in your case you would need to host the script locally).

For more details see [this](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/01/adding-css-js).

Comment: Where would i put the Js files in my yesod bundle of my project for it to be bundled properly?

Comment: You can put static files in the "static/" subdirectory, and then refer to it using the automatically generated "StaticR" type.  For instance if you put the js in "static/scripts/onion.js" you can just add "addScriptRemote $ StaticR scripts_onion_js" (unverified, but I am pretty sure it will work as I typed it).